# clojure use threading macro for equation

Tags: clojure

I have this equation in java that I want to translate into clojure:

```
limit = (int)(n*(Math.log(n) + Math.log(Math.log(n)))) + 3;
```

I want to avoid it turning into a sea of nested parenthesis, what is the best way of making this readable in clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `let` form to break the formula to simpler parts:

```
(defn calc-limit [n]
  (let [log (Math/log n)
        loglog (Math/log log)
        logsum (+ log loglog)]
    (-> n (* logsum) int (+ 3))))

(calc-limit 256) ; => 1861
```

Comment: It may be a matter of taste, but I would rather put logsum on first place. In a sense, logsum is a value that is "treaded", not n.

Comment: @si14 In my opinion, they are equivalent even from point of view what is "threaded", `n` or `logsum`. If `loglog` and `logsum` would be not introduced in first place then I agree that `(-> log Math/log (+ log) (* n) int (+ 3))` would be more idiomatic. In example above additional bindings were created for clarity purpose only. Besides, final expression looks close to original infix notation, which some people may consider as a plus.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with the other answers that a `let` with some descriptive names is a little more enlightening to read. But if you want to do it with just a threading macro, that is possible using `ìterate`:

```
(defn calc-limit [n]
      (->> n
           (iterate #(Math/log %))
           (drop 1) ;;The first value is just n, with no logarithms applied
           (take 2) ;;Taking the 1st and 2nd iterations of Math/log on n
           (reduce +)
           (* n)
           int
           (+ 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Graph](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing), especially if your formulas will grow bigger and if the speed isn't that much of an issue:

```clj
(use 'plumbing.core)
(require '[plumbing.graph :as graph])

(def limit-graph
  {:log    (fnk [n]  (Math/log n))
   :loglog (fnk [log] (Math/log log))
   :logsum (fnk [log loglog] (+ log loglog))
   :limit  (fnk [n logsum] (-> logsum (* n) int (+ 3)))})

(def calc-limit (graph/compile limit-graph))

(:limit (calc-limit {:n 5}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention the threading macro in your question's title, so I'll provide a variant primarily focused on exactly that, using `let` to avoid calculating `(Math/log n)` twice:

```
(let [x (Math/log n)]
  (-> (Math/log x)
      (+ x)
      (* n)
      (int)
      (+ 3)))
```

*Side Note*: Using `let` makes sense when

- you've values that have to be used more than once,
- you want to improve understandability by expressively naming intermediate results, or
- you want to improve readability by splitting up your problem into smaller parts.